# android emulator not showing the login page data

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

As you can see:

[image]

the emulator has been loaded quite well, but only the application name is showing, not the login page output where I have put username, password and login button.

Comment: post your xml and java code

Comment: set your `setContentView(R.layout.login);` in the `onCreate()` method   there must be your login layout .................

Comment: There are two oncreae methods. Have you coded one with single parameter?

Comment: did you call data from internet service?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
}
```

And make sure that your login activity set as LAUNCHER activity in AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: hey thanks a lot. The thing is i am a rookie so forgot to set login as my launcher, did that and it worked, Thank U :)